# How to decode struct pointer with function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linux-kernel

I know how struct pointers work in general. But for `struct spi_controller * spi_busnum_to_master(u16 bus_num)`,

1. What is holding the address of the `struct spi_controller` it is pointing towards ?
2. Can someone decode the logic of this declaration?. ( this style creating struct pointers)

From my understanding, a struct pointer is to enable a variable hold the address of some structure that it points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct spi_controller * spi_busnum_to_master(u16 bus_num)` declares `spi_busnum_to_master` to be a function taking a parameter of type `u16` and returning a pointer to `struct spi_controller`.

The return value is passed by whatever method is defined by the Application Binary Interface for the target platform. Often it is in a processor register.

Comment: Got the initial part, But what is it returning the value to ?.  I am confused b/w how struct pointers work in this case . Lets say, `struct  test * one = & two` .                                                                     Here I am expecting `one` to hold the address of a `struct test` defined as `two`. In my question, What is my one?

Comment: @ali_cr8: First, `struct spi_controller * spi_busnum_to_master(u16 bus_num)` does not define any object to hold an address. It declares a function, the same as a function like `int foo(int x)`. The function is just a part of a program that does things and, in these cases, returns a value. Where you put that value is up to you; in order to use the returned value, you need to use the function in an expression (including an assignment). Second, in `struct test *one = &two;`, `one` is a variable just like `x` in `int x = 3;`. The compiler assigns memory for it as needed.

Comment: so lets say, `struct spi_controller *ptr = spi_busnum_to_master(u16 bus_num)` . Here `ptr` would hold the address of a `struct spi_controller` which is returned by `spi_busnum_to_master(u16 bus_num)`. Is my understanding correct?.

Comment: @ali_cr8: Yes, that is essentially correct. (Technically, the function could return a null pointer, so it is not actually pointing to a `struct spi_controller`. Or it could return a pointer to memory that has not yet been initialized, so there is no actual `struct spi_controller` there yet. But in the case where the function returns a pointer to a completed object, it is a pointer to a `struct spi_controller`.)